# How to enable blinking on mintty (Cygwin Terminal) on Windows 10

Tags: bash, terminal, cygwin, mintty

I read that mintty supports blinking text but do not know how to set it up so I can display blinking text. eg `echo -e "\e[6mMy blinking text\e[0m"`

I Googled it but nothing comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print text with blink attribute :

```
echo "$(tput blink)Blinking text$(tput sgr0)"
```

`tput sgr0` reset colors

You need to start mintty with :

```
mintty -o AllowBlinking=yes
```

Comment: Thanks That's what I needed. I started the Cygwin Terminal by using the `mintty -o AllowBlinking=yes` command in the shortcut that starts the Cygwin Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the line in ~/.minttyrc